# How to create custom index for ebean?

Tags: indexing, ddl, ebean

I'm using [ebean](http://www.avaje.org/), it's very easy to use but I don't know create my custom index.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    public String name;

    // how to create index for this column?
    public long displayOrder;
}
```

I tried to create index for the column `displayOrder`, but how to do it?

There is no annotation for this, and the generated ddl file will be recreated each time, so I can't add my own ddl statements there. And it's not convenient to add index in database directly.

Is there any simple solution to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct answer, but I think, that you should concern on it for a while.

AFAIK there's no way to declare 'KEY' index via annotations, you can only add `@Column(unique=true)` to it (if you need an unique field).

Of course for primary key you just need to use `@Id` annotation.

On the other hand I do not recommend using automatic DDL creation every time - remember, that will destroy all your DB structure and data after next evolution applying!!! Instead go with this way:

- prepare as much models as possible in the first step, and use automatic DDL to apply it to the DB
- Disable Ebean's auto generation
- Start using own evolutions (2.sql, 3.sql etc) for adding missing elements - like for an example missing indexes.
- Never turn back :) From now you need to ALTER an existing tables instead CREATE them every time from the scratch.

Comment: I still hope there will be an `Index` annotation to make things easier. Thanks for your suggestions.